# ASP.NET Protx gotchas

Tags: asp.net, protx

Does anyone have any experience of hooking up an ASP.NET application to protx?

I am looking for things to be aware of and any gotchas as well as a high level summary of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing an integration as we speak and quite frankly it's been a right pain in the hoop. I strongly advise avoiding the exceedingly poor SagePay ASP.NET Integration Kit from the site. It's not .NET at all. It's obviously some ported ASP version. Utterly inefficent and convoluted.

I grabbed the dotnetcharge library from www.dotnetcharge.com. Be aware though, that their support (priority support no less), is a joke. It was $125 and in fairness, it works quite well. The biggest problem I've had is with the 3D Secure. It's an abject nightmare. There is little to no documentation and what does exist is often the dirge that SagePay have pumped out.  SagePay are the biggest joke when it comes to support, they seem to operate a 'cut n paste' reply policy to support emails that contain certain words by the looks of things. I've had emails that are word-for-word the same except for a different sendee and with no regard to the question I asked!

I can plop some of the code I have here using the dotnetcharge library, but you'll find it really easy to be fair.

I hope this helps and good luck!